# What is the *code-conversion-work* buffer

Tags: buffers

What is exactly the purpose of the `*code-conversion-work*` buffer and why is the variable `default-directory` in the `*code-conversion-work*` buffer set to the folder in which Emacs was built?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's part of the "coding system" machinery (source code is in `src/coding.c`).

```
CODING SYSTEM

A coding system is an object for an encoding mechanism that contains
information about how to convert byte sequences to character
sequences and vice versa.  When we say "decode", it means converting
a byte sequence of a specific coding system into a character
sequence that is represented by Emacs' internal coding system
`emacs-utf-8', and when we say "encode", it means converting a
character sequence of emacs-utf-8 to a byte sequence of a specific
coding system.
```

Listed examples of coding systems are:

- UTF-8
- UTF-16
- Charset-base coding system
- Old Emacs internal format (emacs-mule)
- ISO2022-base coding system
- SJIS (or Shift-JIS or MS-Kanji-Code)
- BIG5
- CCL
- Raw-text
- No-conversion

The `*code-conversion-work*` (n.b. has leading space) buffer is described in the source as:

```
A working buffer used by the top level conversion.  Once it is
created, it is never destroyed. [...] The other working buffers are
destroyed after the use is finished, and their names are modified
versions of [this name].
```

I don't know definitively why `default-directory` for this buffer is the source code directory. Obviously we can see that it's the directory where `coding.c` lives, so that *might* be the reason. Typically a new buffer not associated with a file path simply inherits its default directory from the previous buffer. My guesses would be that either this buffer is created very early in the bootstrap process and that directory is the earliest default value for `default-directory`; or else it may be part of the dumped binary when Emacs is built, in which case that value certainly makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful answer. To expand on it a bit:
Where is it set up?
How do I convince Emacs to again auto save it correctly?
Today, I started seeing the following error message: Error (auto-save): Auto-saving *code-conversion-work*: Opening output file: Permission denied, /#*code-conversion-work*# I can surmise some prefix got nulled by something, but what? Where?
I do not even ask why (I probably caused it in a clumsy attempt to "fix" something. Newbee the Bufoon.

Comment: @SheemonLists I believe that buffer is not intended to be saved to a file, so I think the fact that Emacs even wants to do that would be your main problem.  `C-h v buffer-file-name` would normally be `nil` in that buffer.